# simplifying $e^\frac{-t}{4} (\frac{-1}{4})+(\frac{-1}{4}t+1) e^\frac{-t}{4}(\frac{-1}{4})$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Im stuck yet once again simplifying a derivative i get so close to finishing a problem then i spend an hour trying to do something that should otherwise be simple.
simplifying $$e^\frac{-t}{4} (\frac{-1}{4})+(\frac{-1}{4}t+1) e^\frac{-t}{4}(\frac{-1}{4})$$
the answer in the back of my book says this.
$$\frac{1}{16}e^\frac{-t}{4}(t-8) $$

here are the steps i have taken that have not let me to this answer at all

```
1- factor
```

$$\frac{1}{4}e^\frac{-t}{4}([\frac{1}{4}t+1])$$

```
2-distribute
```

$$\frac{1}{16}e^\frac{-t}{4}t-\frac{1}{4}e^\frac{-t}{4} $$
where I'm i going wrong?

Comment: The expression you started with, if I am reading the parentheses correctly, does not simplify to the textbook answer. It seems likely the original expression is not parenthesized properly.

Comment: I believe the expression $e^\frac{-t}{4}(\frac{-1}{4})$ is incorrectly suffixed

Comment: i apologise i made a mistake while writing this down. i have edited the question correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a common factor of $\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)e^{-t/4}$. Bring it "out." We get 
$$\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)e^{-t/4}\left(1+\left(\frac{-1}{4}t+1\right)\right).$$

Simplify the term  $1+\left(\dfrac{-1}{4}t+1\right)$. First rewrite $\dfrac{-1}{4}t+1$ as $\dfrac{-t+4}{4}$. then $1+\dfrac{-t+4}{4}=\dfrac{-t+8}{4}$.
So we have reached
$$\left(\frac{-1}{4}\right)e^{-t/4}\left( \dfrac{-t+8}{4} \right).$$
Finally, change signs and combine the two $4$'s, to get $\dfrac{e^{-t/4}\left(t-8\right)}{16}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your factoring. Once you factor out $-\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$ the other term is actually $[1+(-\frac{t}{4}+1)]=(2-\frac{t}{4}) = \frac{8-t}{4}$.

Thus, the result is $$\left(-\frac{1}{4}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}\right)\left(\frac{8-t}{4}\right) = e^{-\frac{t}{4}} \left(\frac{t-8}{16}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it in a way that's a little more standard first.

-$\frac{1}{4} e^{−\frac{t}{4}}$ - $\frac{1}{4}$$e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$(-$\frac{1}{4}t + 1)$

Then distribute before you start to factor.

-$\frac{1}{4} e^{−\frac{t}{4}}$ + $\frac{t}{16}e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$ - $\frac{1}{4}$$e^{-\frac{t}{4}}$

Then factor it from here.